# Server Sent Events not received from a self-made server

Tags: c++, server-sent-events, libuv, uvw

I'm trying to set up a web server using [uvw](https://github.com/skypjack/uvw), a wrapper around [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv). I've got the server to a point, where i can send out simple responses, and it works without issues. I wanted to add a SSE route, but no matter what I've tried, i cannot get the browser to properly receive the events I'm trying to send out. Is there something I'm missing about sse? I've already had success adding delay to a normal html response, but no matter what i change, the client (I'm using Javascripts EventSource) doesn't report any events, and neither does the network tab of the developer tools.

My code:
main.cpp

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <uvw.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
    
using HttpRequestHandler = std::function<void(std::string_view header, uvw::TCPHandle& socket)>;

// Global (yeah) registry of http request handlers
std::map<std::string, HttpRequestHandler> httpHandlers;

// Utility functions for sending messages to tcp sockets 
void send (uvw::TCPHandle& target, std::string message) {
    target.tryWrite(message.data(), message.size());
}
void send (std::shared_ptr<uvw::TCPHandle> target, std::string message) {
    send(*target, message);
}

int main () {
    // Create the loop
    auto loop = uvw::Loop::getDefault();
    // Make a handler for our server
    auto tcp = loop->resource<uvw::TCPHandle>();

    // Setup logic for incoming connections
    tcp->on<uvw::ListenEvent>([](const uvw::ListenEvent& event, uvw::TCPHandle& server){
        std::shared_ptr<uvw::TCPHandle> connection = server.loop().resource<uvw::TCPHandle>();

        // Setup dealing with the other side disconnecting
        connection->once<uvw::EndEvent>([](const auto&, uvw::TCPHandle& connection){ connection.close(); });
        // Setup loging errors
        connection->on<uvw::ErrorEvent>([](const uvw::ErrorEvent& err, uvw::TCPHandle& connection) {
            std::cerr << "Error @ " << connection.sock().ip << ':' << connection.sock().port << "; Message: "
                << err.what() << '\n';
        });

        // Setup dealing with the request
        connection->on<uvw::DataEvent>([](const uvw::DataEvent& event, uvw::TCPHandle& connection){
            std::string_view msg {event.data.get(), event.length};
            
            // Extract the request path
            const auto firstSpaceIndex = msg.find(' ');
            const auto secondSpaceIndex = msg.find(' ', firstSpaceIndex+1);
            std::string_view requestPath {msg.data()+firstSpaceIndex+1, secondSpaceIndex-firstSpaceIndex-1};

            // TODO: Authenticate the other side

            // Use the apropriate handler
            if (httpHandlers.contains(std::string(requestPath))) {
                httpHandlers.at(std::string(requestPath))(msg, connection);
            }
            // Or if there's no good handler, just 404
            else {
                std::string http404Message = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n";
                connection.write(http404Message.data(), http404Message.size());
                connection.close();
            }
        });

        // Connect the prepared connection object with an actual request
        server.accept(*connection);
        // Start reading the data we're getting
        connection->read();
    });

    // Select a port
    tcp->bind("127.0.0.1", 4242);
    // and connect to it
    tcp->listen();

    // Open the file with the response of our index page
    std::ifstream indexPage ("resources/page.html");
    std::string indexPageMessage {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(indexPage), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};

    // Register the index handler
    httpHandlers["/"] = [message = indexPageMessage](std::string_view header, uvw::TCPHandle& socket) -> void {
        socket.write(const_cast<char*>(message.data()), static_cast<unsigned int>(message.size()));
        socket.close();
    };

    // Register the SSE route handler
    httpHandlers["/gameEvents"] = [](std::string_view header, uvw::TCPHandle& socket) -> void {
        std::cout << "Connecting to gameEvents\n";
        
        // Setup the timer
        auto timer = socket.loop().resource<uvw::TimerHandle>();

        // Send the headerss
        send(socket, 
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/event-stream\r\n"
            "\r\n\r\n"
        );

        // Deal with other side closing
        socket.on<uvw::CloseEvent>([timer = timer->shared_from_this()](auto& ev, auto& socket) {
            timer->close();
            socket.close();
        });

        // React to timer ticks
        timer->on<uvw::TimerEvent>([socket = socket.shared_from_this()](auto& event, auto& timer){
            if(socket->writable()) {
                std::cout << "timer sending timer event\n";
                send(socket, "event: timer\n");
            } else {
                std::cout << "timer encountered unwriteable socket, ignoring for now\n";
            }
        });

        // Trigger the above handler every 5 seconds
        timer->start(uvw::TimerHandle::Time{510}, uvw::TimerHandle::Time{5000});
    };

    // Start the show
    loop->run();
    // Cleanup after ourselfs
    tcp->close();
}
```

and resources/page.html

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello, world!</h2>
    <script>
        const myEventStream = new EventSource("/gameEvents");
        myEventStream.addEventListener('message', ev => {
            console.log('sse event');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, i was a dumbass, and i didn't send my newlines right.
The line

```cpp
send(socket, "event: timer\n")
```

should instead have been

```cpp
send(socket, "event: timer\r\n\r\n")
```

I wasn't sending an extra newline to signify the end of an event, so for the browser i was just sending a single, super long event. Also, my javascript was broken - `myEventStream.addEventListener('message', ...)` would listen to events with the name 'message', not react to any messages.